# Невозможно создать snapshot для БД

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create database AW_Snapshot_Sample on
(name='AdventureWorks_Data', 
FILENAME='D:/mdf/AW_S.ss')
AS SNAPSHOT OF AdventureWorks
```

Код вызывает ошибку:

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Database 'AdventureWorks' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Проблема на участке кода:

```
AS SNAPSHOT OF AdventureWorks
```

Поскольку следующий код создаст БД без ошибок:

```
  create database AW_Snapshot_Sample on
    (name='AdventureWorks_Data', 
    FILENAME='D:/mdf/AW_S.ss')
  --comments  AS SNAPSHOT OF AdventureWorks
```

Ecли создать БД ранее `create database AW_Snapshot_Sample` то как добавить потом возможность снимка ?

Comment: Database 'AdventureWorks' does not exist - база AdventureWorks не существует.

Comment: Ecли создать БД ранее create database AW_Snapshot_Sample то как добавить потом возможность снимка ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Снимок это копия существующей базы. В примере у вас подразумевается что

- существует база AdventureWorks
- создается ее снимок с именем AW_Snapshot_Sample

На практике у вас:

- существует база AW_Snapshot_Sample (вы ее создали через `create database AW_Snapshot_Sample`)
- вы пытаетесь сделать ее снимок.

Выберите имя для снимка (не AW_Snapshot_Sample, оно уже занято вашей базой).

```
create database AW_Snapshot_Sample2 on -- <-- тут должно быть имя создаваемого снимка
(name='AdventureWorks_Data', 
FILENAME='D:\mdf\AW_S2.ss')
AS SNAPSHOT OF AW_Snapshot_Sample -- <-- тут должно быть имя существующей базы.
```

Ну или удалите базу AW_Snapshot_Sample, заранее создайте базу AdventureWorks, и потом уже создавайте для нее снимок:

```
DROP DATABASE AW_Snapshot_Sample 
GO

CREATE DATABASE AdventureWorks
GO

create database AW_Snapshot_Sample on
(name='AdventureWorks_Data', 
FILENAME='D:\mdf\AW_S.ss')
AS SNAPSHOT OF AdventureWorks
```

Comment: получилось только путь задав не через / а \ иначе Error

Comment: @koza4ok я копировал ваш код, не проверял. сейчас подправлю.